# How to get `config` value in `$scope` object?

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I am configuring the `adaptive templating` on config phase in angular module. But all my controller required the config value. how to pass the `config` value to my `$scope` object?

So i can check the `media` in which template i am using?

here is my code :

```
"user strict";

angular.module('responsive', ['ngRoute', 'matchmedia-ng', 'adaptiveTemplating'])

.config(function (adaptiveTemplatingProvider) {

  var isMobile = window.matchMedia('(max-width: 767px)').matches; //how to set to $scope ?
  adaptiveTemplatingProvider.addTest('mobile', isMobile);

  var isDesktop = window.matchMedia('(min-width: 1024px)').matches; //how to set to $scope ?
  adaptiveTemplatingProvider.addTest('desktop', isDesktop);



})

.config(function ($routeProvider, $locationProvider) {

    $locationProvider.html5Mode(true);

    $routeProvider
    .when ("/", {
        templateUrl : "views/{mobile}{desktop}/home.html", //this is working according to the viewport.
        controller  : "homeController"
    });

})

.controller("homeController", function ($scope) {

    if($scope.isMobile) { // how to get here from config?
        console.log("i am mobile");
    }

    if ($scope.isDesktop) {
        console.log("i am desktop!")
    }

})
```

**UPDATE**

```
  angular.module('responsive', ['ngRoute', 'matchmedia-ng', 'adaptiveTemplating'])

    .config(function (adaptiveTemplatingProvider, $window) { //passing

      var isMobile = $window.matchMedia('(max-width: 767px)').matches; //how to set to $scope ?
      adaptiveTemplatingProvider.addTest('mobile', isMobile);

      var isDesktop = $window.matchMedia('(min-width: 1024px)').matches; //how to set to $scope ?
      adaptiveTemplatingProvider.addTest('desktop', isDesktop);

    })
```

in case if i use `window` it works instead `$window`. what is the reason? how to inject `$window` for my scenario?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [library method](https://github.com/ghengeveld/angular-adaptive-templating#function-gettests) `getTests`

> ### {function} getTests()
>
> Retrieve all registered tests.
>
> ```
> @returns {Object} Hash of all tests.
> ```

**UPD:** don't forget inject `adaptiveTemplatingProvider` as dependecy. And do not use `window` use [$window](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$window) instead.

**UPD 2:** Pretty dirty solution will look like this:

```
!function () {
    "user strict"; 

    // as matchMedia is component from angular-match-media
    // you can use this module directly instead of this hook
    window.HOOK = {
        isMobile: window.matchMedia('(max-width: 767px)').matches,
        isDesktop: window.matchMedia('(min-width: 1024px)').matches
    };

    angular
        .module('responsive', [
            'ngRoute', 
            'matchmedia-ng', 
            'adaptiveTemplating'
        ]) 
        .config(function (adaptiveTemplatingProvider) { 
            adaptiveTemplatingProvider.addTest('mobile', window.HOOK.isMobile); 
            adaptiveTemplatingProvider.addTest('desktop', window.HOOK.isDesktop); 
        }) 
        .config(function ($routeProvider, $locationProvider) { 
            $locationProvider.html5Mode(true); 
            $routeProvider 
                .when ("/", { 
                    templateUrl : "views/{mobile}{desktop}/home.html", 
                    controller  : "homeController" 
                }); 
        }) 
        .controller("homeController", HomeController);

    function HomeController() {
        console.log(window.HOOK);
    }
})();
```

But I highly recommend you to spend more time to discover `angular-match-media` and find out how it can be used in your case.

Comment: Can you please update in my code? - that would be much thank ful

Comment: Please see my update in my question. in case if i use `$window` it throw error as 'Uncaught Error: [$injector:modulerr] `

Comment: @3gwebtrain did you read my doc link I provide for `$window` service? It has example of useage.

Comment: @3gwebtrain Check it https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/di The config method accepts a function, which can be injected with "provider" and "constant" components as dependencies. Note that you cannot inject "service" or "value" components into configuration.

Comment: @3gwebtrain `adaptiveTemplating` provide strange usage exapmle in this case. Any way "The run method accepts a function, which can be injected with "service", "value" and "constant" components as dependencies. Note that you cannot inject "providers" into run blocks."

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/81105/discussion-between-3gwebtrain-and-outoftime).

Answer (score 0):

Initialize it in a constant as:

```
app.constant('ngSettings', {
    configIsMobile: isMobile ,
  configIsDesktop: isDesktop,
});
```

Inject it in the controller as:

```
.controller("homeController", function ($scope, ngSettings) {

    $scope.isMobile = ngSettings.configIsMobile;
    $scope.isDesktop = ngSettings.configIsDesktop;
    if($scope.isMobile) { 
        console.log("i am mobile");
    }

    if ($scope.isDesktop) {
        console.log("i am desktop!")
    }

})
```

Answer (score 0):

May be it's better idea to config routs in .run block and move all app settings to separete service(factory) file, that can return them with injection. You can inject to run block anything you want.

Example:

```
angular.module('yourAppApp.globalSettings',[]).factory('globalSettings', function (adaptiveTemplating, $window){
    var isMobile = $window.matchMedia('(max-width: 767px)').matches; //how to set to $scope ? adaptiveTemplatingProvider.addTest('mobile', isMobile);

    var isDesktop = $window.matchMedia('(min-width: 1024px)').matches; //how to set to $scope ?
    adaptiveTemplatingProvider.addTest('desktop', isDesktop);

    var Settings = {
       isMobile: isMobile,
       isDesktop: isDesktop
    };

   return Settings;
});

angular.module('yourAppApp', ['yourAppApp.globalSettings']).
   run(['$routeProvider', '$locationProvider',run]).
   controller(['globalSettings','$scope', homeController);

function run($routeProvider, $locationProvider) {
    $locationProvider.html5Mode(true);

    $routeProvider
      .when ("/", {
      templateUrl : "views/{mobile}{desktop}/home.html", //this is working according to the viewport.
      controller  : "homeController"
    });
}

   function homeController(globalSettings, $scope) {
      if(globalSettings.isMobile) { // how to get here from config?
        console.log("i am mobile");
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you show me a demo or tutorial please? I am not expertised with `angular`.